# Are these two matrices necessarily entrywise-nonnegative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm stuck reading a proof from a paper:

If the matrix $A$ is entrywise-nonnegative, then so is $A^m$ for $m=1,2,...$

Now we decompose $A = C + D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $a_{11}, ... , a_{nn}$, so that I think the paper means that $C$ should have zeros along its diagonal.

Now, is $A^m - C^m - D^m$ also nonnegative?  Here's where I feel the paper has made a jump in conclusion.

Although the matrix $(C+D)^m$ is nonnegative, it's not really clear to me that either $C^m$ or $D^m$ by themselves are necessarily entrywise-nonnegative.

Have I overlooked something obvious?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect $C$ and $D$ independently. It should be clear that $D^m$ is entry-wise nonnegative because $A$ is entry-wise nonnegative. Something similar can be said for $C^m$. In computing the product $C\dotsm C$, we are only multiplying and adding nonnegative terms, so we can successfully argue that the result is a matrix with nonnegative entries.

Comment: Hi @AOrtiz, what you say about $D^m$ is true, but what you say for $C^m$ is not: consider the matrix with 0,-1 on the first row, 2,0 on the second row, and square it.  Your first entry on the upper-left-corner of the 2x2 matrix is -2.

Comment: @user58865 your matrix is itself not one of the matrices the OP is considering. The matrix has to be *entry-wise nonnegative*. Yours has negative entries in it. Thank you.

Comment: A is nonnegative, implies (C+D) is nonnegative, not that C itself is nonnegative...

Comment: @user58865, you are missing the fact that $C$ is built from the entries of $A$. The diagonal of $C$ is entirely zeroes, but all of its off-diagonal terms are the entries of $A$. Since the entries of $A$ are each nonnegative, every term in $C$ is also nonnegative.

Comment: You're absolutely correct - thanks so much for your help, @AOrtiz :)